# Use image sizes

Tags: android

Is there a way to use an image size when setting the sizes of a view? I want to create a TextView item with the exact height of a resource image, but I don't want to use the image as a background for the text view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can get the height of the image, you can use TextView's [setHeight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setHeight%28int%29). If you read in the image as a [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html), you can get the image's height with [getHeight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getHeight%28%29).

Comment: Thanks. I created a custom text view and overridden the onMeasure method. The image height I've got it using getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.header).getMinimumHeight()